# PHP Change Array Structure / Format

Tags: php, sql

I have an array at present that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language] => English
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language] => Arabic
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [language] => Bengali
        )
)
```

What I'd like to do is change it so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [language] => Array
        (
            [0] => English
            [1] => Arabic
            [2] => Bengali
        )
)
```

I also have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
       [id] => 3
       [name] => lethalMango
       [joined] => 2010-01-01 00:00:00
)
```

And I'd like to change it to:

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
           [id] => 3
           [name] => lethalMango
           [joined] => 2010-01-01 00:00:00
        )
)
```

I've tried a number of methods without much success but I'm sure there is an more efficient way.

Comment: It's hard to compare the efficiency of our proposals with your code given that you don't share it with us...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FIRST : 

$result = array();
foreach($array as $value){
  $result['language'][]= $value['language']
}



SECOND : 

 $result['user'] = $array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Works a treat

Answer (score 1):

Second

```
$result = array('user'=>$array);
```

Comment: hehe. Gaurav wrote the solution for the first array first and then edited the second one into it ;) However, this one is slightly different and it doesnt require `$result` to exists before the array is assigned, so I keep the answer :)