# I want to store the 0 indexes of name,email,contact in new array and vice versa all data

Tags: php, laravel, append

[**My result is that the appended data look like this on form request in laravel**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l9Y5.png)

**I want this type of array in my result the first data of append block store in single index and then vice versa all data**

```
name=>basit 
email=>kashif@gmail.com  
contact=>5454 
])  
sub_contact => array([ 
name=>basit 
email=>hamza12433@gmail.com  
contact=>53543
])
```

Comment: you want to save the input data into database that way??

Comment: @zahid hasan emon yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Change Array Structure / Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962277/php-change-array-structure-format)

Comment: @sean i see that php change Array Structure/ Format my data is changed from this data and will not help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your request array structure. Just loop through an element and insert values into database.

```
foreach($request->name as $key => $value){
    Model::create([
        'name' => $request->name[$key],
        'email' => $request->email[$key],
        'contact' => $request->contact[$key],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: the data is in appended form user can add multiple data in your case the last inserted get just get the other data is not get

Comment: show me your form and controller code. you are doing some mistakes maybe.

Comment: i posted the pic above see my coming data and then tell next instruction what i do

Comment: share the controller code. you should try the way i answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop one of the subarrays and use the key in a array_column to get all the values.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);

foreach($arr[$keys[0]] as $index => $value){
    $result[] = array_combine($keys, array_column($arr, $index));
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/kUPi4

---

Or nest the foreach to get the values that way.
I believe this method is faster than array_column one.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $index => $item){
        $result[$index][$key] = $item;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/DCP5W